# Lead conversion - map a non-global picklist value to global picklist value

Tags: picklist, field-mapping, leadmapping

I'm hitting a problem with Lead conversion where I want to map a field with picklist values to a field with a global picklist of values.

The values are valid (Yes or No) in that they are the same as in the global picklist of the target field, but they are still rejected.

Is there a solution other than creating a new target field that does not use a global picklist?